# Why do derived simple ctypes act differently in ctype Structure

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes

Take for example:

```
import ctypes

class struct1(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('field1', ctypes.c_uint32)]
```

When I create this structure and access "field1" I get:

```
var = struct1()
print var.field1  #=> 0L
```

Though, if I derive `ctypes.c_uint32` I get different results:

```
class uint32(ctypes.c_uint32):
    pass

class struct2(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('field1', uint32)]

var2 = struct2()
print var2.field1  #=> uint32 object
print var2.field1.value  #=> 0L
```

I would have assumed that `struct1` would have had `field1` require that the  'value' datamember be accessed in order to obtain the actual value of the ctype, similarly to `struct2`. What am I missing? I want `struct2` to act similarly to `struct1` for backwards compatibility reasons.

**Note:** I am using Python 2.7.3

Comment: It's simply not designed to call the `getfunc` on a subclass. The same applies when the type is set as the return type of a function. See [`_ctypes_simple_instance`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l2823) and `PyCData_get`. Note that due to a rename a few versions ago the name `_ctypes_simple_instance` implies the opposite of what the function actually checks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. That is very unfortunate. I am not sure how I am going to implement backwards compatibility with the previous version of the structure. I tried to overload things like the __add__ operator to add the ".value" of the new structure and it always seemed to throw an exception no matter what I try.

Comment: You can rename the fields as private values, e.g. `'_field1'`, and then add `property` descriptors that get and set each private field's `value`.

Comment: As a result type you can implement `_check_retval_`. It's a `staticmethod` with a single parameter, the return value instance. You can return the `value` as the overall return value of the C function call.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If possible I would like to also display a deprecation warning when someone tries to use `field1` without specifying `.value`. So `var2.field1 + 5` would give you the same value as `var2.field1.value + 5` but it would also print a deprecation warning. The hard part is that I need to support both styles, and also provide that warning.

Comment: I see; you actually want to preserve the subclass type when accessed as a field or result type, but you want the subclass to interoperate as before, just with a warning. This is actually simple to do in Python 2. Implement `uint32.__coerce__(self, other)`. First call `warnings.warn` to provide a `DeprecationWarning`. Then try to `return coerce(self.value, other)`. If there's a `TypeError`, then `return NotImplemented`.

Comment: In Python 3 I'm afraid you'll have to implement all of the binary operators and their reflections. This works in 3.x, unlike 2.x, since coercion was removed. Specifically, in 2.x if a `PyTypeObject` lacks the flag `Py_TPFLAGS_CHECKTYPES`, as is the case for ctypes types, then all arguments to slot functions are guaranteed to be of the object's type, coercing if necessary. OTOH, if the flag is present, as it is for the built-in number types, then the slot function is expected to do its own coercion, if any. This the only option in Python 3, since `__coerce__` was removed.

Comment: I looked into this a couple of years ago to answer [ctypes reimplementation of rshift for c_ulong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15570610/205580).