# python operator overloading for mismatched types does not work if the first type is a ctypes type

Tags: python, operator-overloading, ctypes

Here is the code:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class T:
...     def __and__(self, other):
...             return 1
...
>>> T() & T()
1
>>> T() & "1"
1
>>> T() & 1
1
>>> T() & c_ulong(3)
1
>>> c_ulong.__and__ = lambda self, other: 1
>>> c_ulong(3) & c_ulong(2)
1
```

All good so far. But why doesn't the code below work in Python 2.7.2?

```
>>> c_ulong(3) & T()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'c_ulong' and 'instance'
>>> c_ulong(3) & 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'c_ulong' and 'int'
```

For a class that I define, there seems to be no problem to support any type of second operand, but when I am attaching the function to a ctypes type, the function is called when the second operand is of the same type, but not if the operand is of a different type.
I really want to allow bitwise and and or between ctypes integers and regular integers where the result is a ctypes integer.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. All of the cases work fine for me, all return 1, even the last 2. The only way I would get the error you're getting is by not running the lambda first. If I don't run the lambda command first, then I would get the same error. So are you sure you are executing the lambda command first?

Comment: In Python 2, the `_SimpleCData` class lacks the `Py_TPFLAGS_CHECKTYPES` flag, so you have to implement `__coerce__`. @bbkglb, you must be using Python 3. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15575341/205580).

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for. I was using Python 2.7.2.

Comment: I would like to mark eryksun's answer above as accepted and correct, but I do not know how, there seems to be no button for that.

Comment: @C.Szabo: He'd need to post it as an answer; comments can't be accepted.